# .change event fired twice in Opera

Tags: javascript, dom, opera

Why is .change event fired twice on input type=number fields in opera (im using version 12.14 build 1738)?
Works perfectly ok in all other browsers. If i change to type=text for example, it works as intended.
See example at http://jsfiddle.net/936mn/

```
 $(function(){  
    $('.inter').change(function(){  
    alert("huh");});
 });
```

Comment: It may because your browser may sets the value to 0 after each alert

Comment: Kindly check the value of your input box after the first alert because i don't have opera with me now

Comment: Does it fire twice if you remove the `alert`? (Use `console.log` instead). It could be that Opera fires the change event when the input field looses it's focus.

Comment: Input element has new value after first alert.
Same result on console also.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine here but is probably a bug in Opera regarding its integration with the platform you're using.